# Some Image not showing on page (Laravel 5.7 on AWS Ubuntu)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, laravel-5

I finished set AWS, it works fine. But some images not showing. `history5.jpg` is showing normally not the others. And other images on different root are fine. It uploaded successfully

[image]

[image]

How can I render this images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is case case-sensitive to files names, and As shown in your screenshot **history5.jpg** is lower-case and the other photos are in Upper-case, so try changing the files extensions to lower-case, it might be this is the problem.